# How to convert a value to date format like yyyy-mm-dd - angular

Tags: angular, date-pipe

I'm trying to convert a value to yyyy-MM-dd format. Basically for 06th july 2020 I'm getting date value like this '20200706'. Now i want to convert this value to 2020-07-06.

Currently i'm trying to convert like this, but this is not giving correct result.

```js
fillDateFormatter(dateVal) {
  return this.datepipe.transform(dateVal, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
 };
this.fillDateFormatter('20200706');
```

So do we have any predefined functions to convert date format like above or how can we convert..
seeking for some guidance. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would install [momentjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment) npm package. It allows lots of options to manipulate date/time. In your case it would work like this..

```
console.log(moment('20200706').format('YYYY-MM-DD')); //output: 2020-07-06
```

Hope it helps.

Thanks.